# PHP/Javascript Bypass user input to display div

Tags: php, javascript, user-input

I have a page where if you click on a link, it exposes a div that using ajax displays content from a dbase.

After a user edits this content on the server, I'd like to use PHP to return the user to that page.  This is no problem using a redirect

```
 header("location:page.php")
```

However, when the user comes back to the page, ideally, I'd like to have the content in the div open automatically so the user can immediately see edits without having to find the link to open the div and click on it.

Is this possible, either with something in the url to fire the javascript or alternaively, when you load the page with a certain parameter, triggering javascript to open the div.

The code to open the div is a simple javascript call:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showDiv()">View Content</a>
```

showDiv just uses ajax to display something from the server using responsetext.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header("location:page.php?show=1")
```

Then in page.php **body** tag:

```
<body <?php if($_GET['show']==1) { ?>onload="showDiv()"<?php } ?>>
```

Comment: Is there any way to overwrite the existing body tag for this page only as the body tag is in a template.  Otherwise, I would have to have the above code in every page on the site just for this one instance.

Comment: For example, could I just put the onload event handler in a script tag?

Comment: I put the onload handler in a style tag and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: there is the **window.onload** method: `<script>window.onload = showDiv</script>`